# how do I install the djpeg binary?

Tags: apt

I have a suite of scripts which I require and which make extensive use of djpeg.  but 'which djpeg' returns nothing.  How do I get the djpeg binary installed on my raspberry?

Comment: To search for packages use apt-cache e.g. "sudo apt-cache search djpeg" (which gets the results in the answer below)

Comment: @rob: brilliant!  thx for the nugget.  |K<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs
```